# JavaScript Google spreadsheet words split and no space function

Tags: javascript

I am a new leaner and trying to make two functions ( google spreadsheet script). My understanding of java-script is low, but I want to start with basics to build my understanding. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Split words. JoshRainbow => Josh Rainbow
2. No space.  noSpace("Josh","Rainbow") => "`JoshRainbowJosh`"

   `function split("ab"){
       Var a;
       Var b;
       return ("a"" "" b")
       }`

   `function noSpace("a","b")
    var a;
    var b;
   return ("aba")`

   }

Answer (score 1):

For your first Function to Split on Uppercase Letters use this function

```
function split(input)
{
    return input.replace( /([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
}
```

You will run into an issue with names that have an uppercase letter in the middle of them. First names like AshLea or LuAnn, or any Mc Las name like McDonald.

For your Second Function on concatenating the 2 parameters together use this one.

```
function noSpace(input1,input2)
{
    return input1 + input2 + input1;
}
```

The thing you will want to remember in making a function is that the parameters do not get quotes around them like a string. And when concatenating variables and strings do them like below.

```
 "join with a string " + var1 + " " + var2
```

remember to variables without quotes and strings in quotes, those can also just be spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked and its nice to see how different codes for one aim!

Comment: If you feel this answer is correct, and solves your problem best please give it a thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your exactly after, but it seems you want two functions. One to Split words at uppercase characters and one to concatenate words, so something like these perhaps

```
function split(input)
{
     return input.replace(/([A-Z])/g,' $1').trim();
}
```

this uses a regex and a numbered captured group to find all the uppercase character (i.e. [A-Z]) and then replace it with a space and the same character (the ' $1'). I added a trim at the end, and it will also do the first character, so that will mean there is a space at the front, so the trim removes that.

```
function noSpace(word1,word2)
{
    return word1 + word2 + word1;
}
```

This simply takes in two variables (word1 and word2) and then returns a concatenation of word1 and word2 and word1.

I think you were initially along the right sort of lines, but when you enclose something in quotes (either single or double. i.e. " or '), that is a string literal in javascript. A function the has return "aba" at the end, will always simply return the string "aba" it is not using the variables a or b from the function.

Anyway hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

First one you can do this:

lets say we have a string: Hello that is passed into the function

```
passedValue = "Hello"

function split(passedValue){
    return passedValue.split("");
}
```

This will split your string into array of elements:
H, e, l, l, o

Now you can work with the returned array to get what you like from it, I would recommend reading up on arrays.

Second one is simple:

```
var first = "John"
var last = "Doe"

function concatinate(first, last){
    return first+last;
}
```

In this case you may want to use method .trim() this will remove any white space around any of the words for example if someone passes value "John " there is a white space at the end of it.

There is lot you can do with String, my suggestion would be to Google same Java String tutorials.

Best of luck with your project